# menu entries are lost

Tags: menus

Suddenly I cannot add any menu entry via the "Menu" settings option (....wp-admin/nav-menus.php).

Any new menu I set results in de-selecting the currently selected menu and saving a "null" menu structure in my homepage!

Any help would be greatly appreciated because my home page is affected/

Thank you

Comment: what have you changed? did you installed a new plugin etc?

Comment: Nothing I know of. Should I try disabling plugins?

Comment: yes.. try to disable all plugins and active a default theme.

Comment: It turns out that my users attempted to insert a new menu entry with cache plugin enabled. And maybe the menu files are corrupted. Do you know of any method to fix this?
Thank you.

Comment: @p.a. As an ***[edit]*** !